# Comparison of two array elements and calculation

Tags: arrays, perl, counter

I have an issue with a section of code I wish to write. My problem is based around two arrays and the elements they encompass.

I have two arrays filled with numbers (relating to positions in a string). I wish to select the substrings between the positions. The elements in the first array are the start of the substrings and the elements in the second array are the ends of the substrings.

The code I have supplied reads in the file and makes it a string:

```
>demo_data
theoemijono
milotedjonoted
dademimamted
```

String:

```
theoemijonomilotedjonoteddademimamted
```

so what I want to happen is to extract the substring

```
emijonomiloted

emimamted
```

The code I have written takes the the first element array and compares it with the second array corresponding element and then to ensure that there is no cross over and hence hold the substring to start with emi and end with tedas seen in the provided sequences

```
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{

    if ($rs1_array[$i] < $rs2_array[$i] && $rs1_array[$i+1] > $rs2_array[$i])
    {
        my$size= $rs2_array[$i]-$rs1_array[$i]+ 3);
        my$substr= substr($seq, $rs1_array[$i],$size);
        print $substr."\n";
    }
}
```

Using this code works for the first substring, but the second substring is ignored as the first array has fewer elements and hence the comparison cannot be completed.

***UPDATE***

Array structures:

```
@rs1_array = (4, 28);
@rs2_array = (15, 22, 34);
```

Hi borodin, You were absolutely correct.. I have edited the code now! Thank you for seeing that in relation to the length issue. The reason for the strange offset is that the value in @rs2_array is the start position and it does not take into consideration the remainder of the word "ted" in this case and I require this to complete the string.The Array is built correctly as for the elements in @rs1_array they represent the start position "emi" the @rs2_array elements also hold the start position for each "ted" so as there are 2 emi's and 3 ted's in the string this causes the unbalance.

Comment: Can you please show the data that is in the arrays when you run it?

Comment: I smell an XY problem. Have you considered using regexes to extract the substrings you're looking for? `my @substrings = $seq =~ /emi.*?ted/;`, perhaps?

Comment: Your code may produce the correct output, but it is for the wrong reasons. `$rs2_array[0]` is `15`, so you are calculating `$size = 15 - (length('15') - 1)` or `15 - (2 - 1)`. If the output is correct then it is entirely by chance.

Comment: The data in `@rs2_array` doesn't correspond to the strings you say you want to extract. The first substring starts at offset `4`, ends at offset `18`, and has length `14`. The second substring starts at offset `28`, ends at offset `37`, and has length `9`. The values in `@rs1_array` are correct for the start offsets, but those in `@rs2_array` seem unrelated, and there is even one too many! I think you have built this array incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @starts = ( 4, 28 );
my @ends   = map $_+3, ( 15, 22, 34 );

my $starts_idx = my $ends_idx = 0;
while ($starts_idx < @starts && $ends_idx < @ends) {
   if ($starts[$start_idx] > $ends[$ends_idx]) {
      ++$start_idx;
      next;
   }

   my $length = $ends[$ends_idx] - $starts[$start_idx];
   say substr($seq, $starts[$start_idx], $length);

   ++$ends_idx;
   ++$start_idx;
}
```

Which, of course, gives the same output as:

```
say for $seq =~ /(emi(?:(?!emi|ted).)*ted)/sxg;
```